# Visual Studio - File Open And Close Action Trigger

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on a project where the challenge to track the file open / closed by user in Visual Studio IDE > Solution explorer and write it in notepad with file name.

Can any one suggest some idea to achieve the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you want to monitor Visual Studio to find what files open/close in Visual Studio and log it into a txt file?

Comment: Yes to log the project files open / closed and log it in txt file

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to [DTE.Events.DocumentEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.documentevents?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) **DocumentOpened** and **DocumentClosing** events from a Visual Studio extension to track them.

Comment: yes DocumentEvents may help to achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For such tasks, two approaches my work.

One is to get this from extension API, if developers provisioned such possibility. So, for Visual Studio, check [Visual Studio SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2017), if it provides method for this.

Another one is events monitoring approach, that is applicable to many applications. You will need to use Process Monitor and/or Spy++ to identify some events that will be used to identify opening and closing a file. Then further steps depend on event of interenst, it may be file change notification, windows hooks, API hooks, etc.

Comment: thank you for the direction VS SDK, will give a try on this.